# Ktor: Chunked stream has ended unexpectedly: no chunk size

Tags: kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I am running a Spring Boot application (3.0.4) in Kotlin (1.8.10) which should (in one of its parts) download files from a third party server. This downloading of files is executed from a consumer of a rabbitMQ queue (done with spring-integration but should not matter much, i hope).

Under normal operation there are around a couple of hundredths messages, thus the equal amount of downloads and no problem. The messages are processed one by one in a couple of minutes.

When i do a - lets call it: initial import - with tens of thousands of messages generated, after a while (the time differers), i encounter a this exception:

```
java.io.EOFException: Chunked stream has ended unexpectedly: no chunk size
    at io.ktor.http.cio.ChunkedTransferEncodingKt.decodeChunked(ChunkedTransferEncoding.kt:76)
    at io.ktor.http.cio.ChunkedTransferEncodingKt$decodeChunked$3.invokeSuspend(ChunkedTransferEncoding.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuation.resumeWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:205)
    at io.ktor.utils.io.internal.CancellableReusableContinuation.resumeWith(CancellableReusableContinuation.kt:93)
    at io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel.resumeReadOp(ByteBufferChannel.kt:2167)
    at io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel.tryTerminate$ktor_io(ByteBufferChannel.kt:404)
    at io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel.close(ByteBufferChannel.kt:151)
    at io.ktor.utils.io.ByteChannelKt$ByteChannel$1.close(ByteChannel.kt:32)
    at io.ktor.utils.io.ByteWriteChannelKt.close(ByteWriteChannel.kt:177)
    at io.ktor.utils.io.ByteReadChannelKt.copyAndClose(ByteReadChannel.kt:272)
    at io.ktor.utils.io.ByteReadChannelKt$copyAndClose$1.invokeSuspend(ByteReadChannel.kt)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

Here is a screenshot of the exception in the debugger:
[breakpoint hit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A15hP.png)

When doing a plain curl request of the exact same resource referenced from the execption i get a valid response and all looks good.

When setting a breakpoint at ChunkedTransferEncoding.kt:76 i see that the `_state` of the `input` (ByteBufferChannel) is `terminated` (as compared to `writing` for non error cases).

And now i am lost. I have no idea why the `input` is not writable (any more? any longer?) and would love to get some help in finding the reason. Maybe even fixing it :)

Here are the (hopefully relevant) code fragments. Let me know if you need more/different code.

Ktor (2.2.6) client:

```
    @Bean
    fun httpClient(
        httpSettings: MyHttpSettings
    ): HttpClient {
        return HttpClient(CIO.create { requestTimeout = 1000 * 60 * 5 }) {
            defaultRequest {
                header("api-token", httpSettings.apiAccessToken)
                host = httpSettings.host
                url {
                    protocol = URLProtocol.HTTPS
                }
            }
            install(Logging) {
                logger = Logger.SIMPLE
                level = LogLevel.NONE
            }
            install(HttpTimeout) {
                requestTimeoutMillis = 5 * 60 * 1000
            }
            expectSuccess = true
        }
    }
```

Downloading method:

```
    private fun downloadFile(file: Path, url: String): Path {
        runBlocking {
            try {
                httpClient.prepareGet(url).execute { httpResponse ->
                    val channel: ByteReadChannel = httpResponse.bodyAsChannel()
                    while (!channel.isClosedForRead) {
                        val packet = channel.readRemaining(
                            DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE.toLong()
                        )
                        while (!packet.isEmpty) {
                            val bytes = packet.readBytes()
                            file.appendBytes(bytes)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    Files.delete(file.toAbsolutePath())
                }
            }
        }
        return file.toAbsolutePath()
    }
```

Thanks for reading this far and regards,
Ullrich

Comment: This seems to be a race condition bug. Can you please file an issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=KTOR) with the attached code that generates a sample stream of messages?